# Reading PDF file with Azure Synapse Notebooks

Tags: python, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

It's my first post, asking for a help, before I usually used examples from Stack overflow, but can't find and answer. I am sorry, if the formatting of my post is not great, will try to improve it for the future.

I am struggling with reading PDF files from Azure Date Lake Gen 2 with Azure Synapse Notebooks.

***Updated information: I am using Azure Synapse within the virtual network with private endpoint access to the storage.***

Reading CSV file is not problem, I can access CSV with command:

```py
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://**accountname**.dfs.core.windows.net/**file.csv**'
## If header exists uncomment line below
##, header=True
)
display(df.limit(10))
```

But when I tried to read PDF, it's always failing.
I used libraries like `pypdf2` and `camelot`.

```py
pdf_file = "abfss://**accountname**.dfs.core.windows.net/**file.pdf"
# Open the PDF using PyPDF2
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
```

I receive an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I tried to mount storage location as mentioned in this post - [How can I read pdf or pptx or docx files in python from ADLS gen2 using Synapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77807555/how-can-i-read-pdf-or-pptx-or-docx-files-in-python-from-adls-gen2-using-synapse)

Still can read CSV file from that mounted storage, but not PDF.

```py
mssparkutils.fs.mount( 
    "abfss://container@accountname.dfs.core.windows.net/", 
    "/TR", 
    {"LinkedService":"linkedservice"} 
)

# can get a path, this command is working:
path = mssparkutils.fs.getMountPath("TR")
print(path)

import PyPDF2
with open("/synfs/mount#/TR/file.pdf") as f:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)
```

Gives an error:

> OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error:

I tried to read using path, still not working.

```py
file_name = path + "/file.pdf"
print(file_name)
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open(file_name, 'rb'))
```

gives an error: OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tried to use PyPDF2:

```
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file_name)
```

Gives an error:

> logger_warning(
> 310         "PdfReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. "
> 311         "It may not be read correctly.",
> 312         **name**,'

Please advice, if you know how to solve it.
I am using Azure Synapse Studio, not SDK.

Comment: hi @Pashket can you try this
 !pip install PyPDF2



# Then mount the storage location 

from notebookutils import mssparkutilsmssparkutils.fs.mount( "abfss://mycontainer@<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net", "/test", {"LinkedService":"mygen2account"} )

# get mounted path
path = mssparkutils.fs.getMountPath("/test")
file_name  = path + '/filename'

# now read the file 
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(open(file_name, 'rb'))

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula I got the same error after running that code:
    277         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    278         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    279         "you can use builtins' open."
    280     )
--> 282 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)

OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/synfs/148/test/file.pdf'

Comment: what version of `PyPDF2` is used? try restarting spark session and read pdf

Comment: I tried different versions of PyPDF2 - 3.0.1 and 2.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when storage accounts are accessed via Private Endpoints on a Virtual Network.

> - If the above-created Linked Service to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 uses a [managed private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-managed-private-endpoints) (with a *dfs* URI), then we need to create another secondary managed private endpoint using the Azure Blob Storage option (with a **blob** URI) to ensure that the internal [fsspec/adlfs](https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs/blob/main/adlfs/spec.py#L400) code can connect using the *BlobServiceClient* interface.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api#mount-by-using-a-linked-service-recommended) documentation for more information.

So, create a Blob Storage private endpoint and try the code below.

```py
import PyPDF2

jobId = mssparkutils.env.getJobId()

path=f"/synfs/{jobId}/TR/pdf/bob.pdf"

print(path)

pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(path)
number_of_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
```

You can also refer to this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1053984/error-(errno-5)-input-output-error-when-opening-ad).

If it is urgent, for now, you can copy the file and read.

```py
import PyPDF2

jobId = mssparkutils.env.getJobId()

path=f"synfs:/{jobId}/TR/pdf/bob.pdf"

mssparkutils.fs.cp(path,"file:/tmp/t_pdf/bob.pdf")
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader("/tmp/t_pdf/bob.pdf")
number_of_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
```

Here, I am copying the file to the `tmp` folder and reading from there.

Comment: Hey @JayashankarGS thank you so much!
You are right, Azure Synapse is part of a Virtual Network with private endpoints. 
The second option worked, for the first one I'll need to create a private endpoint (missing peace I was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution using binary file format and byte array, without using a mount drive.

```
import PyPDF2
import io
# PDF file path
pdf_file_path = f"abfss://{containerName}@{storageName}/Folder/test.pdf"

# Load the PDF file using Spark's binaryFile method
pdf_binary_data = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(pdf_file_path)

# Extract the binary content of the PDF file
pdf_content = pdf_binary_data.select("content").collect()[0][0]

# Convert the binary content to a Python bytearray
pdf_bytearray = bytearray(pdf_content)

# Use PyPDF2 to read the PDF file from the bytearray and extract the total number of pages
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(io.BytesIO(pdf_bytearray))
num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

# Print the total number of pages
print("Total number of pages:", num_pages)

# Get the first page
first_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

# Extract text
text = first_page.extract_text()
```